# How can I validate multiple fields in a form using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate multiple fields in a form.

First off, I do not have any experience in JS but after some research I have put together this code and it works for the most part. If all fields are left blank then my error messages pop up. They also pop up if I start answering the form from the bottom and going up. However, if a value exists in the first field being validated then the whole form is submitted.

I apologize for the extremely long and messy code, I imagine there is many ways I can shorten my code but like I said I do not have much experience.

Below is my Javascript code

```
     function validateForm() {

  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["flight_num"].value;
  var d = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
  var t = document.forms["myForm"]["time"].value;
  var f = document.forms["myForm"]["friendliness"].value;
  var s = document.forms["myForm"]["storage"].value;
  var c = document.forms["myForm"]["comfort"].value;
  var cl = document.forms["myForm"]["clean"].value;
  var n = document.forms["myForm"]["noise"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
   document.getElementById('flighterr').innerHTML="Please enter your flight number.";

if (d == null || d == "") {
     document.getElementById('dateerr').innerHTML="Please enter the date of your flight.";

if (t == null || t == "") {
     document.getElementById('timeerr').innerHTML="Please enter the time of your flight.";

if (f == null || f == "") {
     document.getElementById('frienderr').innerHTML="Please select a choice.";

if (s == null || s == "") {
     document.getElementById('storageerr').innerHTML="Please select a choice.";

if (c == null || c == "") {
     document.getElementById('comforterr').innerHTML="Please select a choice.";

if (cl == null || cl == "") {
     document.getElementById('cleanerr').innerHTML="Please select a choice.";

if (n == null || n == "") {
     document.getElementById('noiseerr').innerHTML="Please select a choice.";
   return false; }
   return false; }
   return false; }
   return false; }
   return false; }
   return false; }
  return false;  }
    return false;}
    }
```

Here is the updated javascript code

```
    function validateForm() {

    var validation = [{
    field: "flight_num",
    msg: "Please enter your flight number."
        },
        {
    field: "date",
    msg: "Please enter the date of your flight."
        },
        {
    field: "time",
    msg: "Please enter the time of your flight."
        },
        {
    field: "friendliness",
    msg: "Please select a choice."
        },
        {
    field: "storage",
    msg: "Please select a choice."
       },
       {
    field: "comfort",
    msg: "Please select a choice."
       },
       {
    field: "clean",
    msg: "Please select a choice."
      },
     {
    field: "noise",
    msg: "Please select a choice."
     },
     ];

   var ok = true;

    for( var i = 0; i < validation.length; ++i ) {
        if( !document.getElementById( validation[i].field ).value ) {
     document.getElementById( validation[i].field + 'err' ).innerHTML = validation[i].msg;
    ok = false;
       }
    }

    return ok;   
        }
```

Below is my html form

```
   <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="test" method="Post"  action="input.php" >
   <table>

   <tr>
   <td>First Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="Optional"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Last Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Optional"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Email: </td> <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Optional" ><span id="errEmail"></span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Flight# </td> <td><input id="flight_num"  type="text" name="flight_num"><Span id="star">* </span><span id="flighterr"></span></td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Date: </td><td><input id="flight_date" type="text" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" ><Span id="star">* </span><span id="dateerr"></span </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>Time: </td><td><input id="time" type="text" name="time" ><Span id="star">* </span><span id="timeerr"></span></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

     <div id="div4">
     <table id="choices">
     <tr id="rows">
     <td id="categ" rowspan="2" width="15%"><Span id="star </span>Friendliness of Staff: </td> 
     <td width="15%"><input id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="No opinion"></td>
     <td width="15%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Poor" ></td>
     <td width="15%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Fair" ></td>
     <td width="15%"><input   id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Good" ></td>
     <td width="10%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Excellent"></td><td width="20%"><span id="frienderr"></span></td></tr>
    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Space for luggage storage: </td>
    <td><input id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="No opinion" ></td>
    <td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Poor"></td>
    <td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Fair"></td>
    <td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Good"></td>
    <td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Excellent"></td>
    <td><span id="storageerr"></span></td> </tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Comfort of seating: </td>
    <td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="No opinion"></td>
    <td ><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Poor"></td>
    <td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Fair"></td>
    <td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Good"></td>
    <td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value=" Excellent"></td>
    <td><span id="comforterr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td </tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td  id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Cleanliness of aircraft: </td>
    <td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="No opinion" ></td>
    <td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="Poor"></td>
    <td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" Value="Fair"></td>
    <td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="Good"></td>
    <td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" Value="Excellent"></td>
    <td><span id="cleanerr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td><td>Excellent</td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td  id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Noise level of aircraft: </td>
    <td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" Value="No opinion" ></td>
    <td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" Value="Poor"></td>
    <td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="fair"></td>
    <td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="Good"></td>
    <td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="Excellent"></td>
    <td><span id="noiseerr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr></table>

    <p><Span id="star">*  Required</span></p>

    <div id="div5">
    <table id="button">
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear Data"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use jquery.validate plugin to validate. http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation

Comment: I realize many people recommend jquery but I have no clue how to implement it. For the most part I can read Javascript and understand whats happening.

Comment: please read the documentation. i have sent the link

Comment: @vel I should mention I am very limited on time and need this by tomorrow, so Im not looking forward to starting from scratch after having invested so much time.

Comment: why don't you use HTML5 'required' attribute

Answer (score 1):

This is basic validation i just modified your JavaScript code

```
$('#btnsub').click(function(){
console.log("DS");
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["flight_num"].value;
  var d = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
  var t = document.forms["myForm"]["time"].value;
  var f = document.forms["myForm"]["friendliness"].value;
  var s = document.forms["myForm"]["storage"].value;
  var c = document.forms["myForm"]["comfort"].value; 
  var cl = document.forms["myForm"]["clean"].value;
  var n = document.forms["myForm"]["noise"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please enter your flight number.");  return false;}

if (d == null || d == "") {
     alert("Please enter the date of your flight.");
 return false;}
if (t == null || t == "") {
     alert("Please enter the time of your flight.");
 return false;}
if (f == null || f == "") {
     alert("Please select a choice.");
 return false;}
if (s == null || s == "") {
    alert("Please select a choice.");
 return false;}
if (c == null || c == "") {
     alert("Please select a choice.");
    return false;}
if (cl == null || cl == "") {
     alert("Please select a choice.");
 return false;}
if (n == null || n == "") {
     alert("Please select a choice.");

   return false; }

    });
```

This a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/cbbmeeL9/)**  page

Comment: Hey @shri I would like to have the error message show next to each missing field all at once. Also,in your example if all fields are left blank and the form is submitted it only realizes "flight_num" is missing.

Comment: Hey i have done using HTML 5 just check it if its fine then accept the answer https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/cbbmeeL9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have done using HTML 5 just check it if its fine then accept the answer **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/cbbmeeL9/2/)**

```
    <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="test" method="Post"  action="input.php" >
   <table>

   <tr>
   <td>First Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="Optional" required title="Enter first name"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Last Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Optional" required title="Enter Last name"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Email: </td> <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Optional" required title="Enter Email Id"><span id="errEmail" ></span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Flight# </td> <td><input id="flight_num"  type="text" name="flight_num" required title="Enter Flight No."><Span id="star" >* </span><span id="flighterr"></span></td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Date: </td><td><input id="flight_date" type="text" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"required title="Enter Date" ><Span id="star">* </span><span id="dateerr"></span </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>Time: </td><td><input id="time" type="text" name="time" required title="Enter Time"><Span id="star" >* </span><span id="timeerr" ></span></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

     <div id="div4">
     <table id="choices">
     <tr id="rows">
     <td id="categ" rowspan="2" width="15%"required><Span id="star </span>Friendliness of Staff: </td> <td width="15%"><input id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="No opinion"></td><td width="15%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Poor" ></td><td width="15%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Fair" ></td><td width="15%"><input   id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Good" ></td><td width="10%"><input  id="friendliness" type="radio" name="friendliness" value="Excellent"></td><td width="20%"><span id="frienderr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr>



     <tr id="rows">
    <td id="categ" rowspan="2" required><Span id="star">* </span>Space for luggage storage: </td><td> 
<input id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="No opinion" required title="Select one choice"></td><td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Poor" ></td><td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Fair"></td><td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Good"></td><td><input  id="storage" type="radio" name="storage" value="Excellent"></td><td><span id="storageerr"></span></td> </tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="rows">
    <td id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Comfort of seating: </td><td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="No opinion  title="Select one choice"" required></td><td ><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Poor"></td><td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Fair"></td><td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value="Good"></td><td><input id="comfort" type="radio" name="comfort" value=" Excellent"></td><td><span id="comforterr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td </tr>


    <tr id="rows">
    <td  id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Cleanliness of aircraft: </td><td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="No opinion  title="Select one choice"" required ></td><td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="Poor"></td><td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" Value="Fair"></td><td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" value="Good"></td><td><input id="clean" type="radio" name="clean" Value="Excellent"></td><td><span id="cleanerr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td><td>Excellent</td></tr>



    <tr id="rows">
    <td  id="categ" rowspan="2"><Span id="star">* </span>Noise level of aircraft: </td><td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" Value="No opinion  title="Select one choice"" required ></td><td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" Value="Poor"></td><td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="fair"></td><td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="Good"></td><td><input id="noise" type="radio" name="noise" value="Excellent"></td><td><span id="noiseerr"></span></td></tr>

    <tr id="rows">
    <td>No Opinion</td><td>Poor</td><td>Fair</td><td>Good</td <td>Excellent</td>
    </tr></table>


    <p><Span id="star">*  Required</span></p>

    <div id="div5">
    <table id="button">
    <tr><td><input type="submit" id="btnsub" value="Submit"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear Data"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the logic validateForm() function :

```
function validateForm(){
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["flight_num"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
    //......so on...//

    var IS_VALID = true; // assume form is valid
    var error_msg = '';

    if (x == NULL || x == "" || x == 'undefined') {
         IS_VALID = false;
         error_msg += "flight num can not be blank";
    }

    if (d == NULL || d == "" || d == 'undefined') {
         IS_VALID = false;
         error_msg += "\ndate can not be blank";
    }

    //......do the same for all the elment


   // finally check if the flag is true or false
    if (IS_VALID === false) {
          alert(error_msg);
    }

    return IS_VALID;
}
```